# ImageSlideshow pod getting error "Type of expression is ambiguous without more context"

Tags: ios, swift

i'm using [zvonicek/ImageSlideshow](https://github.com/zvonicek/ImageSlideshow) pod in my project.
when using `AlamofireSource(urlString: "imageURL")` inside `setImageInputs` function, i'm getting this error: `Type of expression is ambiguous without more context`

but when i'm using `ImageSource(image: UIImage(named: "imageName")!)` the error is gone.
this error also happening for `KingfisherSource(urlString: "imageURL")` too.
i'm installed 'ImageSlideshow/Alamofire' and 'ImageSlideshow/Kingfisher' pods but the problem still remainig.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to force unwarp the input Source like this,

```
slideShow.setImageInputs([
            KingfisherSource(urlString: "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/pbMEU4tp0S8/maxresdefault.jpg")!,
            KingfisherSource(urlString: "https://live.staticflickr.com/6221/6372557029_13b7d80ba9_b.jpg")!,
            KingfisherSource(urlString: "https://wallpaperaccess.com/full/2513892.jpg")!
        ])
```

It should work as setImageInuputs should get as a parameter an array [InputSource] and KingfisherSource conform to the InputSource protocol

Answer (score 1):

This type of error is generated when there is type mismatch. Please check the exact type required and pass that value only.

Comment: i know that, i'm copy and paste codes from github.